# Overlapping content inside flex - Firefox doing it wrong

Tags: html, css, firefox

I noticed some strange behavior of elements in Firefox: This is how it looks in Firefox:
[image: ff result]

and this is how it looks in Chromium (expected result)
[image: chromium result].

I tried to strip the whole code into the minimal sample below. Every css property seems to have some effect.

```css
.container {
  display: flex
}

.button-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.my-button {
max-width:fit-content;
padding-left: 1rem;
padding-right: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class=" ">
  part of this text will be overlapped 
  </div>

  <div class="button-container">
    <button type="button" class="my-button ">X</button>
    <button type="button" class="my-button">X</button>
    <button type="button" class="my-button">X</button>
    <button type="button" class="my-button">X</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: According to https://caniuse.com/?search=fit-content, max-width: fit-content is experimental and needs a prefix for FF, and even then FF doesn't implement everything.

Comment: I believe it is caused by compatibility issue of ```fit-content``` of those buttons in Firefox: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max-width#browser_compatibility / https://caniuse.com/?search=fit-content

Comment: This answers my question perfectly. Thanks for the resources!